# Url rewriting .php to .asp

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I would like to redirect my url :
`www.site.fr/displayfichebien.asp?idref=250` to `www.site.fr/detail_offre.php?offre=250`

I have a PHP website and the link `www.site.fr/detail_offre.php?offre=250` work.

But when i put `www.site.fr/displayfichebien.asp?idref=250` in my browser i have a 404 error.

**htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule displayfichebien.asp?idref=([0-9]+)$ detail_offre.php?offre=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: If you put "Redirect 301 / http://twitter.com" as the first line in your htaccess does this redirect your whole site to twitter? If not it might be a apache conf issue, if it does then there is an issue with your htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot match `QUERY_STRING` in `RewriteRule`. You need to use a `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^idref=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule displayfichebien\.asp$ detail_offre.php?offre=%1 [QSA,L,NC]
```